# Google Apps Script Triggers not firing - but only sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a few scripts that I want to run overnight so I've set up script triggers to execute these.  Its all pretty straightforward stuff and they run fine.  But occasionally, say once a month, one of them fails to execute.  No error messages are sent to me by Google or anything like that.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Has anyone got any ideas I can check for this error?  Obviously if its the actual trigger that's not firing in the first place then the code won't actually run and therefore it won't be able to run any checks.

I'll also flag this with Google themselves in google-apps-script-issues forum.

Answer (score 0):

I have a trigger set to fire every five minutes and a few times a month it will fail. Often it will say something about the function not being found.

You can be notified of an execution failure by setting up an "execution failure notice". In Resources > Current Script's Triggers, after each trigger will be a "notifications" link. Clicking it will open the "Execution failure notifications" window.

You have some choices about timing of the email notification of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: I suspect that, after I edit my code, sometimes the triggers miss fire. But I have never double checked this.

Suggestions:

1) add some logging and at the end of the script, grab the log and email it back to yourself.

2) Add a try catch around your code and email any errors that you catch back to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Google scripts are throttled in various ways and your script may be hitting up against one of these limits.  There are limits on the number of emails you can send and limits on execution time of the script in addition to others.